# Estilo roto en mensaje de nuevos privilegios

Tags: bug, estado-completado, perfil

Al obtener un nuevo privilegio, el estilo del mensaje en mi perfil está roto, y el privilegio ganado es ilegible:

[image: Nuevo privilegio]

No sabría comparar con los otros sitios, a ver qué regla de CSS es la que está rota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arreglado aplicando la sugerencia de Oriol:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De paso he corregido el texto (medalla -> privilegio).

Answer (score 6):

El problema es que la notificación está flotada a la izquierda y no tiene una anchura explícita, así que la anchura viene dada por el texto que contiene (véase el [algoritmo reduce-para-caber](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float)). Como el texto **"¡Has ganado un nuevo privilegio!"** ocupa más espacio que el disponible a la derecha del icono, la notificación salta a la línea de abajo.

Quitar la flotación y generar un [contexto de formato de bloque](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) debería solucionarlo:

```css
.congrats .inner-wrapper .text {
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alternativamente, en lugar de generar el contexto de formato de bloque, se podría quitar la [limpieza](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#clearance) del párrafo:

```css
.congrats .inner-wrapper .text {
  float: none;
}
.congrats .inner-wrapper .text > p {
  clear: none;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]